# previewActionItems not getting called (Force touch action)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using below code to add force touch preview actions... Peek and pop view works great, only actions are not showing... Please help my code is not getting executed for some reason, take a look:

```
- (NSArray<id<UIPreviewActionItem>> *)previewActionItems {

    if (_previewActions == nil) {

        UIPreviewAction *rateAction = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Rate" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {

            EmbededRateViewController *embededRVC = [[EmbededRateViewController alloc]initWithEmployerToRate:self.employersArray[0]];

            embededRVC.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, 210);
            [embededRVC setPopinTransitionStyle:BKTPopinTransitionStyleSnap];

            BKTBlurParameters *blurParameters = [[BKTBlurParameters alloc] init];

            blurParameters.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
            blurParameters.radius = 0.3f; // 0.3
            [embededRVC setBlurParameters:blurParameters];
            [embededRVC setPopinTransitionDirection:BKTPopinTransitionDirectionTop];
            [self.collectionView setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [self presentPopinController:embededRVC animated:YES completion:^{
                NSLog(@"Popin presented !");
            }];
        }];

        UIPreviewAction *commentAction = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Comment" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {

            NewCommentViewController *ncvc = [[NewCommentViewController alloc]initWithEmployer:self.employersArray[0]];
            [self presentViewController:ncvc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];

        UIPreviewAction *reportAction = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Report" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {

            ReportEmployerViewController *reportEmpVC = [[ReportEmployerViewController alloc]initWithEmployer:self.employersArray[0]];
            [self presentViewController:reportEmpVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];

        UIPreviewAction *cancelAction =
        [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   style:UIPreviewActionStyleSelected
                                 handler:^(UIPreviewAction *action,
                                           UIViewController *previewViewController){

                                 }];

        _previewActions = @[commentAction, rateAction, reportAction, cancelAction];
    }
    return _previewActions;

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was facing the same issue was was stuck for long.

The mistake that i did was adding this method in the Caller View Controller.
**DO NOT** add this method in the caller view controller , add it in the called view controller instead.

For example if you are presenting View Controller B (called) on force touch of View Controller A(caller), then add this method to the View Controller B (called).

and was too obvious , because we are handling the button actions in View controller B.

Hope it helps you.
All the best.

Comment: Thanks! Solved the issue for me.